# Cannot make react-router 4 render routes right

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I got that simple app with react, redux and webpack

```
// entry.js
import React from "react";
import {render} from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { Router } from "react-router-dom";
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'

import store from './containers/store/index';
import App from './components/App.jsx';

const history = createHistory();

render((
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <App history={history} />
    </Router>
  </Provider>),
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

If user is not logged in (userInfo is null) then I want path to be `/` and render `Home` component, when a user is logged in I want path to be `/lobby` and render  `Lobby` component.

But despite the path in the browser changes, `Home` component is rendered. Only when I click the second time it renders `Lobby` then. What is my mistake?

```
// App.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import Profile from "./Profile";
import Lobby from "./Lobby";
import Home from "./Home";
import Signin from "./Signin";

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { userInfo: state.userInfo };
};

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  updateHistory() {
    if (!this.props.userInfo && !this.props.history.location.pathname === '/') {
      this.props.history.replace("/");
      this.setState(this.state); // to rerender
    }

    if (this.props.userInfo && this.props.history.location.pathname === '/') {
      this.props.history.replace("/lobby");
      this.setState(this.state); // to rerender
    }    
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.updateHistory()
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    this.updateHistory()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
        <Route path='/lobby' component={Lobby} />
        <Route path='/profile' component={Profile} />
        <Route path='/signin' component={Signin} />
      </Switch>
    )
  }
}

const connectedPage = connect(mapStateToProps, { })(App);

export default connectedPage;
```

Also I have a `Link` on `Home` component which changes the path in the browser navigation panel, but doesn't affect rendered `Home` component at all.

```
// Home.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from 'semantic-ui-react/dist/es/elements/Header/Header';
import Button from 'semantic-ui-react/dist/es/elements/Button/Button';
import Container from 'semantic-ui-react/dist/es/elements/Container/Container';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import l10n from '../../l10n/ru';
import { userRegister } from '../../containers/actions';

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { isRegistering: state.isRegistering };
};

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container className="page-home">
        <Header as="h1" className="page-title">Home</Header>
        <div className="home-text">
          <p>{ l10n.HOME_TEXT }</p>
        </div>
        <div className="link-signin-container">
          <p>{l10n.HOME_SIGIN_TEXT} <Link to="/signin">{l10n.HOME_SIGIN_LINK}</Link></p>
        </div>
        <div className="home-button-container">
          <Button
            size="massive"
            icon="play"
            content={l10n.HOME_PLAY_BUTTON_TEXT}
            labelPosition="right"
            loading={this.props.isRegistering}
            onClick={this.props.userRegister}
          />
        </div>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}

const connectedPage = connect(mapStateToProps, { userRegister })(Home);

export default connectedPage;
```

I'm feeling as if I'm missing something very basic about routing with react-router.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `this.props.location` instead of `this.props.history.location`. See [this part of the docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/history.md).

As for the Link, in this section

```
if (!this.props.userInfo && !this.props.history.location.pathname === '/') {
  this.props.history.replace("/");
  this.setState(this.state); // to rerender
}
```

You are telling the component to redirect to '/' any time there's no user and the route does not match '/'. So the Link changes the route to '/signin', but then it immediately gets changed back to '/'.

Comment: There is no location key in props. Thank to mentioning a logic error in history manipulating. The strange thing is that the path is changing to /signin in the browser navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found out what caused the trouble

The Home and App components are connected to redux store. React-router messes with the store and handles that with `withRouter` function.

As soon as I changed

`const connectedPage = connect(mapStateToProps, { userRegister })(Home);` to

`const connectedPage = withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, { userRegister })(Home));`

and

`const connectedPage = connect(mapStateToProps, { })(App);` to

`const connectedPage = withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, { })(App));`

it'd started working perfectly

for details check out this: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/redux-integration